# C# Error CS0103: The name 'i' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

Can someone give me some insight on my code.  My C# program is suppose to transmit a message from a client to a server but extract and print only the vowels.  But it states that my 'i' doesn't exist please help.

```
// 5. Display the received message:
            Console.WriteLine("[Server] Message of client recieved");
            for (int i = 0; i < totalBytes; i++)
            {
                aChar = Convert.ToChar(incomingDataBuffer[i]);
                Console.Write(aChar);
            }

            {
               aChar = Convert.ToChar(incomingDataBuffer[i]);
               if(aChar == 'a' || aChar == 'A' || aChar == 'e' || aChar == 'E' || aChar == 'i' || aChar == 'I' || aChar == 'o' || aChar == 'O' || aChar == 'u' || aChar == 'U')
               {  
                   Console.Write(aChar);
               }
```

}

Comment: correct, i doesn't exist outside of the for loop, and you reference it outside the loop.

Comment: also, you may want to use `if("aeiou".Contains(char.ToLower(aChar)))` to keep things a bit cleaner

Comment: So then would I only need to get rid of the first }? and keep it open to sync up with the first conver.tochar?

Comment: yes. If you intend it to be in the for loop

Answer (score 1):

You closed the for loop with the first }. The scope of 'i' is limited to the for { ... } body, so the lower Convert.ToChar is out of the scope of the 'i', it no longer exists.

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalBytes; i++)
{
  aChar = Convert.ToChar(incomingDataBuffer[i]);
  Console.Write(aChar);
  aChar = Convert.ToChar(incomingDataBuffer[i]);
  if(aChar == 'a' || aChar == 'A' || aChar == 'e' || aChar == 'E' || aChar == 'i' || aChar == 'I' || aChar == 'o' || aChar == 'O' || aChar == 'u' || aChar == 'U')
  {  
    Console.Write(aChar);
  }
}
```

Would fix it, or you could create two for loops to get the output to be what you want it to be.

Comment: So then would I only need to get rid of the first }? and keep it open to sync up with the first conver.tochar?

Comment: Yes. Updated answer with a code example. Or if that doesn't do what you want it to do, you need two for loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "i" only inside for loop because it's local variable.

Comment: So then would I only need to get rid of the first }? and keep it open to sync up with the first conver.tochar?

Comment: Well your for loop should have closing bracket at the end of this code so everything would be inside for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you meant to include the second part of your code in the for loop, so just need to ensure the closing curly brace is after the second part.

But you can write your code in a simpler way

```
 var s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(incomingDataBuffer);
 Console.WriteLine(s);
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join("",s.Where(c => "aeiou".Contains(char.ToLower(c)))));
```